# Which style is better for a classic dynamic programming if-not-contains-then-put?

Tags: java, performance, dynamic-programming

It is quite normal in dynamic programming problems to have a map that contains previous cases, and every time you reach a new state you have to check if it is already in the map, if so use it, and if not add it. I would like to know what is better in performance and style between these two ways:

```
Value value;
if(!map.contains(key)){
    value = calculateValue();
    map.put(key, value);
} else {
    value = map.get(key);
}
```

and this one:

```
if(!map.contains(key)){
    map.put(key, calculateValue());
}
Value value = map.get(key);
```

The second one seems to be less efficient, but allows me to avoid having an uninitialized variable that could lead to errors some day.

Comment: `Map#get` being O(1) if I'm not wrong, I'm not sure that one is much more performant than the other one. I would personally go for the most readable one, i.e. the second one. Be careful with thread safety though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most readable way is [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). It adds a function call *only* when the value is absent, which should be negligible.

The code would look like:

```
final Value value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> calculateValue());
```

Comment: Java-8 map api changes and syntaxes have defnitely made code more concise and readable.